If we had full comprehension, what other axioms would come for free?
Jech says "replacing full Comprehension by Separation presents us with a new problem. The Separation Axioms are too weak to develop set theory with its usual operations and constructions... notably these axioms are not sufficient to prove that the union of two sets is a set, or to define the notion of a real number."
I would love if someone could spell out, which axioms would we get (union, powerset?) if we had full comprehension?
I see there is a similar question with an answer so I can delete this if it is redundant.

Because theory with full comprehension is inconsistent - we get all axioms we want. For example, we easily get that any set is powerset of any set, any set is union of any family of sets, both axiom of choice and axiom of determinancy, etc.

That's a good one.  We can get anything with an inconsistent theory.  But I guess I mean how many consistent axioms can we get with the idea of comprehension, being able to call out a property.

“I see there is a similar question with an answer” I think people would appreciate it if you could link the similar question you found. You must feel the answer there doesn’t fully answer the question you have in mind, so it’s also better if you could explain why it’s doesn’t answer your question.

What does it mean for an axiom to be consistent? It only makes sense to ask whether a theory is consistent.

Here is the other question/answer. It would be nice to have a clear list of axioms that would fall into the category of "we could have gotten it from comprehension if we had it". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849673/why-are-the-separation-axioms-too-weak-to-develop-set-theory-with-its-usual-ope

I should not have said consistent axiom.  I mean a collection of axioms from the usual axioms that would follow from full comprehension if we had it.

@ErinCarmody literally any well formed formula follows from full comprehension. I am not sure what else is there to say. Or do you mean "can we choose some axioms from full schema of comprehension, such that these axioms follow from normal ZF, and in turn imply, for example, axiom of union"?

Joe, I get that but I'm wondering which of the ZFC axioms we could get from comprehension.

@mihaild I was wondering which axioms in ZFC can be described using a property, in the template of full comprension

Jech mentions union and power set, are there others?

All the axioms that fall into the category of “this definable class is a set”, which is to say, pairing, union, power set, replacement, infinity would be instances of comprehension.

@spaceisdarkgreen thank you! this is what I was looking for. I just wanted someone to spell that out.  If you want to write an answer with any more details that would be great.

As a supplement to Noah's answer...
On the positive side, all of the axioms of the "set construction" variety (pairing, union, power set, replacement) straightforwardly follow from unrestricted comprehension. For instance, the power set axiom is $$ \forall x\exists y \forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow z\subseteq x)$$ which is of the form $$ \forall x\exists y \forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow \phi(z))$$ where $\phi(z)$ is the formula $z\subseteq x.$ Or, if we prefer comprehension notation, the power set axiom says $\{z: z\subseteq x\}$ is a set.
Similarly, replacement says for any formula $\phi(x,y)$, $$ \forall x\in A\;\exists!y\;\phi(x,y) \to \exists z\forall y(y\in z\leftrightarrow \exists x\in A\;\phi(x,y)).$$ Here we can just throw out the part before the first $\to$ and see that the conclusion is an instance of comprehension regardless if that first part holds. In other words, the replacment instance for $\phi(x,y)$ follows directly from the instance of comprehension that says $\{y: \exists x\in A\;\phi(x,y)\}$ is a set.
Morally, infinity goes in this category as well, although it requires a few definitions to state, and can take a few different forms. But the upshot is that you have a definition of natural number, and then infinity just says $\{n: \mbox{$n$ is a natural number}\}$ is a set... it's a comprehension instance.
As Noah mentions, regularity can't reasonably be put into this category. Nor can choice, since, e.g. there can be definable sets like the real numbers with no definable well-ordering. Finally, extensionality doesn't make any kind of existential statement at all, so it clearly doesn't belong in that category.

Thank you this was really helpful, I'm making some images of the axioms and the ones that are not a comprehension instance came out looking a little different from the others.

As noted in the comments, it's a bit difficult to make this question precise since the full comprehension scheme entails everything (being inconsistent). That said, here's one precise observation that might be helpful: comprehension principles "preserve definability," in the sense that the set $$\{x:\varphi(x,\overline{a})\}$$ is (trivially) definable relative to the (possibly empty) tuple of parameters $\overline{a}$.
Several but not all of the standard set-theoretic axioms and constructions share this property. For example, $\mathsf{Regularity}$ does not have this property:

Under mild assumptions, there is a transitive $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ with a definable nonempty element $a$ such that no definable $b\in a$ has $b\cap a=\emptyset$.

This isn't quite trivial; for example, we can't use $L$ here since "the $L$-least element of $a$ which has empty intersection with $a$" would always pick out such a $b$. But it also isn't hard to prove: take, for instance, a (model with a) definable nonempty set of reals with no definable element. See e.g. here.
Of course one's mileage may vary, but this is a precise sense in which $\mathsf{Regularity}$ is not a "comprehension-instance."

Thanks Noah, so is regularity the only one that does not have this "preserve definability" property? How about pairing? And why can't we get union from separation?
